# Open specific page after submission forms sent or not

Tags: javascript, php, forms, alert

I would to open a popup message after my contact form is sent or receive a error popup.
If press close on alert I would to open the index.html page; if there is an error I would to close only the popup so you can't loose the text of the message.

With the actual code I receive the alert message but after close the popup the page load the .php page in the url (blank) but I receive the message in my mail...
Thanks to everyone who can help me with the code ;)

[Pastie Bin php code](https://www.pastiebin.com/593d80ebca959)

Comment: use AJAX for that

Comment: I don't know how to code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

**On Success**

`echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Message Sent!'); 
        window.location = 'index.html';
       </script>";`

**On Error**

`echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('ERROR!'); 
       </script>";`

Comment: I receive this message after press the send button: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'index' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /web/htdocs/www.ortoflorpasino.it/home/sendemail.php on line 24